# Movie related to dreams and a spinning top

Tags: story-identification, movie

I remember seeing a movie in which the hero gets into multiple level of dreams, he even has a family in one dream.

He can find whether he is in a dream or in reality​ only by  spinning a top - if it falls down it is reality, if it keep spinning he is still in the dream.

Answer (score 6):

This is *Inception*, released in 2010.  From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inception):

> The film stars Leonardo DiCaprio as a professional thief who steals information by infiltrating the subconscious, and is offered a chance to have his criminal history erased as payment for a task seemingly-impossible: "inception", the implantation of another person's idea into a target's subconscious.

Also regarding the top -

> Cobb tests reality using his totem, a spinning top that spins indefinitely in a dream world

[image: Spinning top gif]

Comment: Was 2010 so long ago that people can forget the name of this movie? Man I feel old

Comment: I rather suspect the OP is having a bit of fun a la "*I remember a movie with spaceships and laser swords. The main characters, a smuggler, a woman and a young man are chased by the operatives of the evil Emperor*".

Comment: Maybe the OP just forgot the name and is not good at googling stuff.